# PDO Error when connecting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database stored on localhost.

Code:

```
$config['db'] = array( 
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'mypass',
    'dbname' => "dbname"
);

echo $config['db']['host'];

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=sfrtv', 'root', 'usbw', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

This code returns the following error:

> `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)' in H:\path\filename.php:12 Stack trace: #0 H:\path\filename.php(12): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loc....', 'root', 'mypass') #1 {main} thrown in H:\path\filename.php(12) on line 12`

Any suggestion on how to correct this?

Thx!

Comment: You can't connect to your MySQL server. Have you ensured that it's running, you're connecting to the right host, your credentials are correct, etc.?

Comment: It is working, I am able to connect with mysql_connect() but I would rather work with PDO. I am just having difficulty with the syntax.

Comment: [6.2.7. Causes of Access-Denied Errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/access-denied.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure you got the code from Alex, in PHP academy.
Can you try checking your mysql details are the same. Try this, I changed the quotes and white spaces.

```
   $config['db'] = array( 
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'mypass',
    'dbname' => 'dbname'
    );

        echo $config['db']['host']; 

        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='. $config['db']['host'] .';dbname='. $config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
```

Or check back the tutorial again: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQjKkNiByCk

---

And if not, try this way of connecting with the below code, as it will **catch the exception** and echo out what the problem is.

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', 'mypass', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The above way of connecting is much safer, because it something goes wrong it will not display your entire file and directory structure to the user.

Comment: Thanks, and yes I did get this code from the referenced tutorial. When I run the code with the 'try' code I get the following result: ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Comment: @AME That could be from a problem from your localhost. Can you change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @AME localhost is the same as 127.0.0.1, also you said it works fine using mysql_*() It's likely the DSN is being messed up. See my post for a possible reason, and link to the PHP doc for creating a DSN.

Comment: When I replace localhost with the IP, I get the same error - ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)

Comment: @AME have you changed your password, dbname, or server recently ?

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie - I haven't changed my password, dbname or server. I am running a local server from a USB stick using this software: http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/.

Comment: @AME Go to:-`C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.0.51b\bin\mysqld-nt.exe`

and then in the wapserver menu "Restart All Services".

Comment: @AME I don't think you have the PDO MySQL extension enabled, you just have PDO enabled, it has a separate one that needs to be additionally enabled to allow PDO with MySQL. Please see my post.

Comment: The solution was to run the code on a XAMPP based server instead of USBWebserver. Thanks to @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie for the tip.

Comment: It Works for me and solve a great issue !!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` enabled/uncommented in your `php.ini` file otherwise PDO will not support MySQL.

Comment: thanks. The password does not contain any of these characters.

Comment: @AME Make sure you have `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` enabled/uncommented in your `php.ini` file otherwise PDO will not support MySQL then restart server.

Comment: extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll is enabled

Comment: @AME is is after `extension=php_pdo.dll`? It must come after this line.

Comment: it actually comes after ;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll

Comment: `extension=php_pdo.dll` should be first, then it should have `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` the PDO extensions are loaded top to bottom, so the order is important.

Comment: I adjusted the order and the error still persists.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21663/discussion-between-cryptic-and-ame)